# Can I install php 5.6.10 and mysql 5.6 in flash drive

Tags: php, mysql-5.6

I want to use the latest version of Apache PHP and MySQL in flash drive 
And then I'll use it for any computer

Answer (score 2):

I assume you like to have a portable development server with the latest versions of PHP and MySQL ?
In that case it is a good idea to setup a virtual image with vagrant:

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/

1. [Download Virtual-Box itself](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
2. [Download Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/downloads)
3. [Find your favorite Vagrant-Box](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=&provider=&q=mysql%20php)

My favorite is [Ubuntu/trusty64](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64) in this case your step 4 would be to enter the following into your terminal:

4. vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64; vagrant up --provider virtualbox

this will setup everything you need to get a base system.

After that you will do the mysql and php latest installation:

5. either this way ([Lamp](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)) or `sudo apt-get install mysql-server php5-mysql`

After that you can use the flash drive everywhere you have installed virtual-box. Of cause you can use forward the IP of the box and use it with other computers in the network. See vagrant doc and virtual box doc.

Hope this answers your question - elsewhere ask again.

Comment: @AungLay: For the case you like to install the development version (not stable) there are additional repositories. For the most used cases my answer should be the right way. You also would be able to install everything you like and also test different machine simulations to figure out the necessary power of your server for production mode (Virtual Machine Documentation - or different question).